# How to update array using its index in ReactJS? I want to put the value of an object at a particular index in array using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, setstate, array-indexing

I want to put the value of the state object 'nm', to the array 'Names[]' at a particular index 'uid'.
`Please check this code-`

```
    this.state={
        Names:[], nm:'', status:false, uid:''
    }

    upddata=(e)=>{

  **      this.state.Names[this.state.uid]=this.state.nm; **
`THIS LINE WORKS EXACTLY to put the updated data in array but shows warning: Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()`

        this.setState({
            status:false,
            Names:this.state.Names,
        })
        this.setState({nm:''});
    }
```

`The above code is working as expected and updates the data at particular index but it is giving warning. How can do that using this.setState??`
`I want to do this instead to avoid this warning: Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()`

Comment: It's currently unclear how your state should look like. You try to set `Names[someId]` to whatever value `nm` has. What are you trying to logically save in your state?